# Doctrine 2: weird behavior while batch processing inserts of entities that reference other entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, bulkinsert

I am trying out the batch processing method described here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

my code looks like this

```
    $limit = 10000;
    $batchSize = 20;
    $role = $this->em->getRepository('userRole')->find(1);
    for($i = 0; $i <= $limit; $i++)
    {
        $user = new \Entity\User;
        $user->setName('name'.$i);
        $user->setEmail('email'.$i.'@email.blah');
        $user->setPassword('pwd'.$i);
        $user->setRole($role);
        $this->em->persist($user);
         if (($i % $batchSize) == 0) {
             $this->em->flush();
             $this->em->clear();
        }
    }
```

the problem is, that after the first call to em->flush() also the
$role gets detached and for every 20 users a new role with a new id is
created, which is not what i want

is there any workaround available for this situation? only one i could make work is to fetch the user role entity every time in the loop

thanks

Comment: I know it's late, but - the clear() also accepts a parameter, so clear only the User entity: `$this->em->clear(\Entity\User::class);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`clear()` detaches all entities managed by the entity manager, so `$role` is detached too, and trying to persist a detached entity creates a new entity.

You should fetch the role again after clear:

```
$this->em->clear();
$role = $this->em->getRepository('userRole')->find(1);
```

Or just create a reference instead:

```
$this->em->clear();
$role = $this->em->getReference('userRole', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to arnaud576875's answer you could **detach** the $user from the entity manager so that it can be GC'd immediately. Like so:

```
$this->em->flush(); 
$this->em->detach($user);
```

**Edit:**
As pointed out by Geoff this will **only detach the latest** created user-object. So this method is **not** recommended.

Comment: That would only detach the latest user, not the 19 that proceeded it though - correct me if I'm wrong.